# Which ASP.NET server control would you suggest for this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I need to build a web page that has categorized data that looks like the screenshot below. Initially, I thought of using a `Repeater` or a `DataList` but I am not sure. Which ASP.NET control do you suggest? I am working on ASP.NET 4.0

[image]

Comment: I'd probably go with a `Repeater` (or nested `Repeater`s in this case?), mostly because I prefer the control it gives me over the markup (by not adding tons of its own).  But that's just me.

Comment: The image is too wide to be readable. Perhaps shrink the _Percentage_ column or something.

Comment: You can zoom with your browser. I assume you mean shrink the % column in the markup?

Comment: @DotnetDude I meant to shrink the width of the column titled 'Percentage', just for the purpose of the screenshot. The contents of the column don't seem to need that much space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ListView. It will give you the functionality you need with the added benefit of clean markup using the templates.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/10/the-asp-listview-control-part-1-building-a-product-listing-page-with-clean-css-ui.aspx

Use nesting in the templates "if you really have to". Avoid nesting top-level controls like the ListView - totally unnecessary and a performance killer.

Comment: This is a nested control scenario. Are you suggesting using nested `ListView`s?

Comment: No. You can use nesting via the templates by binding smaller controls - avoid the bigger ones.